# $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=0\}\cup\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>0, y=1/x\}$ is not connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This is an example from Munkres' book:

$X=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=0\}\cup\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>0, \ y=\frac 1 x\}$. Why is $X$ not connected? The author explained that neither contains a limit point of the other. What's the limit point in this example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any topological space $X$, $x \in X$ is said to be a limit point of a subset $S \subseteq X$ iff for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $U \cap S$ contains some point other than $x$ itself. This is the definition of a limit point.

If $X$ has a metric topology, then $x$ is a limit point of $S$ iff there exists a sequence of points $\{x_{n}\}$ in $S$, converging to $x$. If you're not sure why this is true, do spend some time proving it - it should follow from the definitions of limits and limit points.

Once you're comfortable with this, you should be able to verify that the sets $A = \{\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid y=0 \}$ and $B = \{\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x > 0, y=1/x \}$ are a) disjoint, and b) that both $A$ and $B$ contain their respective limit points.

Then, you have that neither set contains the other's limit points; and consequently, they are both open and closed in $X = A \cup B$, giving a separation of $X$.

Comment: Can I say that the closure of A and B are two lines? And these lines were composited by many limited points? Also, could these two sets connect at infinity finally? Thanks.